# Shoot bullet from certain rotation and position java

Tags: java, rotation, position

I am having a problem while calculating a bullet's x & y position.
I want the bullet to spawn at the plane's (center) X - 26, Y + 34. The problem is, the plane can rotate around.

This is what I have so far, but it's just spawning the bullet in front of the plane.

```
ServerBullet b = new ServerBullet(ownerId, rot);
b.x = this.x + (float) (Math.cos(rotRad) * 34);
b.y = this.y + (float) (Math.sin(rotRad) * 34);
bullets.add(b);
```

[Where bullet needs to spawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axxZR.png) (Image)
[image]

The bullet needs to spawn at 'X', marked in the image.

Comment: Where is it currently spawning?

Comment: You might need to edit your question to make things clearer. For example: to what object does `this` refer?

Comment: Why do you use 34 in both X and Y calculations?